# Find $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1/2)^n\tanh{(1/2)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^n}\tanh{\left(\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)}$ ?

In general, what is the explicit form of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\tanh{x^n}$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the sum is $\frac{2}{e^2-1}$

Comment: Hint: For the first series, use the fact that $\tanh x=2\coth 2x-\coth x$ and a telescoping argument. By the way, the first series is very similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364986/evaluating-sum-n-0-infty-2-n-tanh-2-n?rq=1).

Comment: @mickep i ask myself if jack's approach also works for the general case

Comment: @tired I encourage you to try it out. I'm cooking, so I don't have the possibility to grab pen and paper at the moment (and when I'm done, I'm sure someone will have _tried_) :)

Comment: I think the question is duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364986/evaluating-sum-n-0-infty-2-n-tanh-2-n?rq=1

Comment: @mickep ok, i think i doesn't because the special choice of $x=1/2$ yields some cancelations which makes it possible to aplly the identity (3) in jack's answer. At least some more work has to be done at this stage of the calculations which is beyond my personal (time-)horizon at the moment.. :(